# ArangoDB Request Load balancing

Tags: cluster-computing, load-balancing, arangodb

I'm currently doing benchmarks for my studies using YCSB on an ArangoDB cluster (v3.7.3), that I set up using the starter [(here)](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/deployment-cluster-using-the-starter.html).

I'm trying to understand if and how a setup like that ( I'm using 4 VMs e.g.) helps with balancing request load?
If I have nodes A,B,C and D and I tell YCSB the IP of node A, all the requests go to node A...

That would mean that a cluster is unnecessary if you want to balance request load, wouldn't it? It would just make sense for data replication.

How would I handle the request load then? I'd normally do that in my application, but I can not do that if I use existing tools like YCSB... (or can I?)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The Java driver supports round-robin load balancing (https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/java-reference-setup.html#load-balancing), but it is not configurable from YCSB, since it only accepts one IP address (https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/cd1589ce6f5abf96e17aa8ab80c78a4348fdf29a/arangodb/src/main/java/site/ycsb/db/arangodb/ArangoDBClient.java#L92).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem as well and ended up solving it by standing-up [nginx](https://nginx.org/) in front of my cluster, providing a stable, language-independent way to distribute query load.  I found nginx surprisingly simple to configure, but take a look at the [upstream](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) module for more details.

```
upstream arangodb {
  server coord-1.my.domain:8529;
  server coord-2.my.domain:8529;
  server coord-3.my.domain:8529;
}

server {
  listen                *:80 default_server;
  server_name           _; # Listens for ALL hostnames
  proxy_next_upstream   error timeout invalid_header;
  
  location / {
    proxy_pass          http://arangodb;
  }
}
```

It's not ideal for everyone but works well for those times when you just need to load-balance and don't want to write a bunch of code (which ends up being quite slow) to resolve coordinators.

I've asked ArangoDB for a native proxy server solution, but I would bet it's low on their to-do list as it could be tricky to support, given the huge number of configuration options.